# MouseWheel c# winforms when wheeling not stoping

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, mousewheel

i will put my problem as easy as i can.

I am working on a .dll for dynamics crm with visualstudio2010(ctrl add in) in c# winforms. First of all, i have a panel(mainPanel) that contains all other controls:

- Then i have a panel(pnContRoles) with autoscroll set to true(it happens that i only use the horizontal scroll due to the project requirements), and with size and position defined.
- With the same position but smaller size i have got another panel pnIntersection that have autoscroll set to false and it is add to the mainPanel.

When i am doing the scroll on pnContRoles all the controls inside it and inside pnIntersection moves good. By the way, all the controls inside the panels are textboxes. 
But, when i intend to do mousewheel operation in the horizontal scroll, the textboxes inside pnIntersection did not move. So in the mouseWheel event of pnContRoles i have said to move the textboxes inside. And all this to say, that the mousewheel is working fine for both panels.

But, here comes my problem, when the scrollbar(on mouseWheel operation) arrives to the ends(minimum and maximum position i suppose), all the textboxes inside pnIntersection and pnContRoles continues to move if i continue to use the Wheel on the mouse.

So, i will put some code to illustrate all this parafernalia, anyone who can give me a hand or point me on the right direction is welcome to post. I am trying to disable the mouseWheel when arriving to the ends but, at the moment, no good luck.

Posting code:

```
private void wheelingPanel(Panel pn, TextBox tb, int saltoX, int saltoY)
    {                        
        pn.MouseWheel += (senderL, eL) =>
        {
                            if (eL.Delta > 0)
            {
                tb.Location = new Point(tb.Location.X + saltoX, tb.Location.Y + saltoY);

            }
            else
            {
                tb.Location = new Point(tb.Location.X - saltoX, tb.Location.Y - saltoY);

            }                                             
        };                                   
    }
```

I did my function so every time i need to use mouseWheel on a panel(pn) with given textboxes(tb).

How can i do, to make the textboxes on pnIntersection stop, when i do mousewheel??

Rafa

Comment: You are violating very basic UI usability rules: it should be *discoverable* so the user doesn't have to read a manual, it should not require unusual hardware to operate.  Simply set the panel's AutoScroll property to True, now the user instinctively knows that the mouse wheel is going to work.  If you still need to help in your code, doubtful, then assign the panel's AutoScrollPosition property.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, like you said it works. Altough i am trying that it works without the two scrolls on the panel. Thanks again.